# C# console application ... factorial application code

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application

I was creating a console application to find the factorial of number N. I used this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter N= ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i = 1;
        while ( i < n)
        {
            n = n*i;
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(n);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work right. The output is a 
negative number. I enter n= 3, and the output = -46798313.

How can I fix this problem?

Note: I have to use a "while loop".

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Some general advice, be very careful when you use a single variable for input and output.

Comment: i am sorry but i don't know what stepping through the code mean ?!

Comment: You never said your problem, but I am going to assume that it never ends and never prints `n`. Please see this link for how to debug your application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: the problem is that the output is a negative ling number ... i enter n= 3 the output = *46798313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter N= ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i = 1;
        int output = 1;
        while (i <= n)
        {
            output = output * i;
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```